# which webhook topic to choose when a product variant updates or adds?

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have created successfully a webhook and all works. So if I add a variant or update a variant I dont recieve any data on my webhook so which topic should I use for creating another webhook to recieve when I update a stock ?

current webhook

```
{
  "webhook" : {
      "address" : "https://xxxx.de/webhooks",
      "topic": "products/update",
      "format": "json",
      "fields": ["id", "note"]
    } 
}
```